# SQL Server: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I get this error when trying to execute my SQL Server Stored procedure: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

This is the part that breaks. Any ideas why? Thank you!

```
IF  @Supervisor = 1 
AND @Calc = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Employees
        SELECT [Employee_No]
        FROM 
            dbo.fx_DetermineEmployeesBase
            (
                @Employee_ID
              , NULL
              , @Employee_ID
              , 2
            )

    ;WITH Applications AS
    (
         SELECT TOP 25
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw.[Fullname] ASC, vw.[Submission_Date] DESC) AS [Row]
          , ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw.[Fullname] ASC, vw.[Submission_Date] DESC) - 1) / @Page_Size) + 1 AS [Page_Number]
          , vw.[Employee_No]
          , CASE 
                WHEN fx.[New_Balance] > vw.[Balance] THEN vw.[Balance]
                ELSE fx.[New_Balance]
            END AS [Predicted_Balance]
        FROM vw_Employee_Leave_Application vw
            FULL OUTER JOIN @Employees e ON
                vw.[Employee_No] = e.[Employee_No]
            --This causes the error:
            --A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
            CROSS APPLY dbo.fx_Employee_Leave_Type_Balance_Predict_LastRow
                (
                    NULL 
                  , COALESCE
                    (
                        CASE
                            WHEN vw.[Start_Date] <= 
                                (
                                    SELECT TOP 1 [End_Date]
                                    FROM vw_Employee_Leave_Planner
                                    WHERE
                                        [Employee_No] = vw.[Employee_No]
                                    AND [Leave_Type_No] = vw.[Leave_Type_No]
                                    AND 
                                    [Accepted] = 1
                                    AND [End_Date] > GETDATE()
                                    ORDER BY [End_Date] DESC
                                )
                            THEN
                                (
                                    SELECT TOP 1 [End_Date]
                                    FROM vw_Employee_Leave_Planner
                                    WHERE
                                        [Employee_No] = vw.[Employee_No]
                                    AND [Leave_Type_No] = vw.[Leave_Type_No]
                                    AND [Accepted] = 1
                                    AND [End_Date] > GETDATE()
                                    ORDER BY [End_Date] DESC
                                )
                            ELSE vw.[Start_Date]
                        END
                      , GETDATE()
                    )
                  , vw.[Employee_No]
                  , vw.[Leave_Type_No]
                ) fx
        WHERE
            (
                vw.[Employee_No] = e.[Employee_No]
            AND vw.Approver_No IS NULL
            )
        OR  vw.[Approver_No] =  @Approver_ID
    ),
    PageSettings AS
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            [Row] AS [Item_Count]
          , [Page_Number] AS [Page_Count]
        FROM Applications
        ORDER BY [Row] DESC
    )

    SELECT
        [Row] AS [Row_Number]
      , [Page_Number]
      , @Page_Size AS [Page_Size]
      , [Item_Count]
      , [Page_Count]
    FROM Applications, PageSettings
    WHERE
        [Page_Number] = @Page_No
    OR  @Page_No IS NULL  
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen on Google, this could be:

[link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/19/sql-server-2005-fix-error-message-when-you-run-a-query-against-a-table-that-does-not-have-a-clustered-index-in-sql-server-2005-a-severe-error-occurred-on-the-current-command/):

> In SQL Server 2005 while testing Indexes I had created a table with
>   one non clustered index only. I did not create any clustered index on
>   table. After that I ran SELECT statement, it gave me following error.
>   I was very surprised when I looked at error. It says Msg 0, what it
>   means is that this error is not known error to Microsoft and it might
>   be bug.
>
> Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the
>   current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. Msg 0,
>   Level 20, State 0, Line 0 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command. The results, if any, should be discarded.
>
> I did search on error and found that it is definitely bug and there is
>   Cumulative update package 6 for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2, which
>   fixes this problem. You can download the Cumulative update package 6
>   for SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2 from here.
>
> To resolve this problem, submit a request to Microsoft Online Customer
>   Services to obtain the cumulative update package. To submit an online
>   request to obtain the cumulative update package, visit the following
>   Microsoft Web site: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=6294451

[Another Link to Download](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910416)

Answer (score 0):

Restore an older backup of the database and try again, it solves mine.